# C# textbox issue

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception

I need a bit of help with this code I am writing to produce and test the different types of loop conditions It has several lines that have errors that are causing the compiler to not build the solution. Don't know if it is the specific library that I am not calling right or if I am missing something in particular with the code. I created a particular folder that stores the correct images that I want the loop to use for the pictureBox, but it still has errors where it states the variable is out of text; it now states that System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'
:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PictureBox
{
    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        
        int num1, num2;
        Image[] Bully = new Image[10];
        int randomNum;

        Image dog= Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Empiric Library\source\repos\PictureBox\PictureBox\Form1.cs");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            pictureBox1.Image = Bully[i];
            i++;


            Bully[0] = Image.FromFile("Bully1.jpeg");
            Bully[1] = Image.FromFile("Bully2.jpeg");
            Bully[2] = Image.FromFile("Bully3.jpeg");
            Bully[3] = Image.FromFile("Bully4.jpeg");
            Bully[4] = Image.FromFile("Bully5.jpeg");
            Bully[5] = Image.FromFile("Bully6.jpeg");
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num1))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out num2))
                {



                    
                    while ( i < num2)
                    {
                      MessageBox.Show("i=" + i);
                      pictureBox1.Image = Bully[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    



                }

            }


        
        }

        private void Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bully[0] = Image.FromFile("Bully1.jpeg");
            Bully[1] = Image.FromFile("Bully2.jpeg");
            Bully[2] = Image.FromFile("Bully3.jpeg");
            Bully[3] = Image.FromFile("Bully4.jpeg");
            Bully[4] = Image.FromFile("Bully5.jpeg");
            Bully[5] = Image.FromFile("Bully6.jpeg");
            if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out num2))
            {
                for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bully Number= " + i);

                    pictureBox1.Image = Bully[i];
                }
            }
        }
        private double Average(int num1, int num2)
        {
            double result = (num1 + num2) / 2;
            return result;

        }
        private void avg1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double res = Average(1, 100);
            textBox4.Text = res.ToString();

        }

     

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string textLine)
        {
            StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Empiric Library\source\repos\PictureBox\PictureBox\Form1.cs");
            // This Reads The First Line Of Text
            // Read The Next Line Of Text
            textLine = fileIn.ReadLine();
            MessageBox.Show("From File ..." + textLine);
            fileIn.Close();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter FileOut = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Empiric Library\source\repos\PictureBox\PictureBox\Form1.cs");
            string str = "BullyProof";
            int number = 16;
            FileOut.WriteLine(str);
            FileOut.WriteLine(number);
            // To Write In Output Stream
            FileOut.Flush();
            // To Close The Stream
            FileOut.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            randomNum = random.Next(1, 42);
            textBox3.Text = randomNum.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where exactly do you get the error about the missing semicolons?

Comment: `Bully{0}` that is some syntax I've never seen before. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: @JohanDonne I had fixed that error due to changing the curly brackets into the solid bracket, but it through lines 34 -39 and lines 75 - 80. Now it states that those line now have a problem with context.

Comment: @Marco just changed it, missed interpreting.

Comment: "...I want the loop to use for the textbox..." - what EXACTLY you want to happen when you Click on `button1`? This explanation isn't such clear.

Comment: Need it to loop an image in the picture box.

Comment: `while ( 1 < num2)` - shouldn't it be `while ( i < num2)`?

Comment: I just changed it and now the problem is that the system can't find the stored memory.

Comment: This is the Error code:

Comment: System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'